# Thymeleaf to replace button click with a link

Tags: thymeleaf

I have my model defining ${entry.name} = 'MyClient'

I have a button with th:id="${entry.name}"

I'm trying to click on this button using a link instead, button will be hidden.

This snipped works as expected:

```
<a name="link_to_my_btn" value="My Btn" href="#" onclick="$('#MyClient').click();">Example</a>
```

But I cannot hardcode MyClient, I need to use entry.name.
Now I try doing via thymeleaf but I can't get it to work correctly.
I've tried:

```
 <a name="my_btn" value="My Btn" href="#" th:data-name="${entry.name}" th:onclick="$('#this.getAttribute('data-name')').click();">Example</a>
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<a name="my_btn"
   value="My Btn" href="#"
   th:data-name="${entry.name}"
   onclick="$('#' + this.getAttribute('data-name')).click();">Example</a>
```

There really isn't a reason to use `th:onclick` -- you aren't evaluating any Thymeleaf attributes.  An onclick attribute + valid JavaScript should get the correct element.

Comment: Thanks, ended up doing something similar  after some trial and error. The '#'+ was my problem.